# Scheduled SQL Server Instance Push to Azure SQL Database

Tags: sql-server, azure, etl, dataflow

I am somewhat surprised (still after all these SQL Server Installed Instance (Windows VM Azure) that pushing data, on a nightly schedule, to an SQL Azure database is not straight forward. I see some articles and direction to 'migrate' schemas and data, but what about a nightly job to push from my SQL Server instance to individual client SQL Azure data stores?

[image]

Should I start with SSIS? Azure data factory? Python libraries? Why isn't a connection between the two 'native'?

Again, all links and references so far have been for one time migration. I want the two in a data Eco-system with reliable flow.

John

Comment: There is a native possibility [stretch db](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/stretch-database/stretch-database?view=sql-server-ver15) to have a cold data store in the cloud.  Otherwise SSIS is a valid possibility.

Answer (score 1):

We do this using SSIS running from the on prem side, because we already have a bunch of SSIS projects hosted on prem, and have yet to migrate anything into azure data factory. We are using SQL authentication to make the connection to the SQL Azure database.

Comment: So it is something simple. What connector are you using in SSIS?

Comment: Native OLEDB (SQLNCLI 11.1)

Comment: I'll be damned. Nothing like feeling dumb on a regular basis.  :)